# How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I think I'm being the victim of a bug here. Sometimes while I'm working (I still don't know why), my network traffic goes up to 200 KB/s and stays that way, even tough I'm not doing anything internet-related.

This sometimes happens to me with the CPU usage. When it does, I just run a `top` command to find out which process is responsible and then `kill` it. Problem is: I have no way of knowing which process is responsible for my high network usage. Both the resource monitor and the `top` command only tell me my total network usage, neither of them tells me process specific network info.

I've found questions here about monitoring total bandwidth usage, but, as I mentioned, that's not what I need. Is there another command I can use to find out which process is getting out of hand?

The command `iftop` gives results that disagree entirely with the information reported by System Monitor. While the latter claims there's high network traffic, the former claims there's barely 1 KB/s.

I've already tried killing all the obvious ones (Firefox, update-manager, Pidgin, etc) with no luck. So far, restarting the machine is the only way I found of getting rid of the issue.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67807/is-there-a-top-like-command-that-shows-the-network-bandwidths-and-file-accesses

Comment: a newer one: [**`bandwhich`**](https://github.com/imsnif/bandwhich)

Answer (score 371, accepted):

I've had a lot of success with [nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs). It has to run as root but there are different ways you can sort the statistics (like KB/s or total bandwidth monitored since nethogs started).

Also, if you use wireless you need to pass the device to it.

Install it with command: `sudo apt-get install nethogs`

Just run

```
sudo nethogs
```

If you want to check the total cumulative sum of bandwidth consumed since you open `nethogs`, do (it's useful to see which programs consume more bandwidth over the long run)

```
sudo nethogs -v 3
```

Comment: On closer inspection it's _really_ annoying that it assumes the terminal is always 80 characters wide and truncates the command.

Comment: `nethogs` is nice, but it seems to use _way_ more cpu on my computer than `iftop`

Comment: Be warned of a bug making some versions of `nethog` unusable: http://askubuntu.com/questions/726601/nethogs-%E2%86%92-creating-socket-failed-while-establishing-local-ip-are-you-root

Comment: nethogs dont retain information. If some program stopped its internet usage, and you had fired up later, you would miss that info and never the defaulting app.

Comment: I ran `sudo nethogs eth5` and got this error: `creating socket failed while establishing local IP - are you root?`. Turns out it was because my version of nethogs was old. `nethogs -V` showed my version was 0.8.0. Apparently v0.8.1 or later fixes this problem, so I followed these instructions to install to the latest, which is 0.8.5: https://askubuntu.com/questions/726601/nethogs-%E2%86%92-creating-socket-failed-while-establishing-local-ip-are-you-root/729560#729560. Now it works perfectly! Note that the latest releases are here: https://github.com/raboof/nethogs/releases.

Comment: Also, nethogs isn't picking up everything at all! System Monitor is showing I'm receiving continually at 47 Mbps (which is HUGE bandwidth usage!), but nethogs isn't showing this traffic at all!

Comment: You're obviously monitoring the wrong interface

Comment: I have the same issue as as @GabrielStaples. I see a huge difference between system monitor and and nethogs.

Comment: @SaTa @Dagelf, still happening. I had 20Mbps upload and download for like 2 hrs straight. No idea what it was. `nethogs` showed no traffic greater than a few kb/sec. I have only one wifi interface so I'm sure I'm choosing the right one. No ethernet cable is plugged in either. Maybe it was an `sshfs` session I had open and could't unmount for some reason? I don't know. I rebooted to stop it.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, In my case it seemed that a lot of the traffic was coming through UDP. Running `sudo nethogs -C` picked up that traffic and started to show values close to sys monitor.

Comment: @SaTa, `nethogs` doesn't have a `-C` option. `nethogs -V` shows my version is `version 0.8.5-2build2`. I installed it on Ubuntu 20.04 just now with `sudo apt install nethogs`. What is your nethogs version?

Comment: @GabrielStaples Yes, the official one does not have it. Clone their repo [here](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs). Then, install Debian/Ubuntu [dependency](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs#debianubuntu) and [build](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs#building). You don't need to install it. It will run after `make` with `sudo ./src/nethogs`.

Comment: @Ben For the -v3 flag.. Do you know how I can get cumulative and per second at same time. Possible?

Answer (score 78):

Use `iftop` to locate the TCP port on your machine that is receiving the most traffic.
Then use `sudo netstat -tup` to locate the process "owning" that port.

That's the process you're looking for.

PS: Should work for UDP too.

Comment: Thanks, the command seems to work, but I'm getting strange results. System monitor claims a total of around 180KB/s, while `iftop` claims a total of barely 1 kilobyte per second.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer since it does answer the original question. But I'll be nice if I can figure out what's going on here.

Comment: iptop displays stats for a single interface. I'm not sure if System monitor looks at only one interface or all of them. If that's the case then there will be traffic shown by System monitor but not shown by iftop, which is OK because you only want to be looking at your internet interface anyway (and not lo). I just tested iftop on my system and it showed what I expected it to. Be aware though that iftop displays averages over 2s,10s,40s respectively. I ran iftop like 'sudo iftop -i eth0 -nPB', how did you run it?

Comment: I ran it as `sudo iftop -B -i eth0`, that means it was only looking at my internet traffic right? It didn't occur to me that the system monitor might be checking other interfaces as well. Ironically, the problem disappeared 10 minutes ago (after many hours), so I can't check `iftop` again for now. What does the lo interface stand for?

Comment: Since there are a lot of numbers on the iftop screen I've created a screenshot where I highlited the number you're interested in. Compare that to System monitor. The screenshot is at http://imgur.com/2iuiI . "lo" stands for localhost, it's an interface through which local programs can communicate with one another.

Comment: Yeah, I had to read the manual to understand what all those numbers where about. Given that they're all averages, they were all pretty low (like, always below 10KB, instead of above 100KB). This problem happened to me twice in the last week. So, if it shows up again, I'll check the numbers again, and I'll check the lo interface too. I'm connected at work, and wouldn't be surprised if their local network is causing this abnormal traffic.

Comment: I'm downloading something with JDownloader and the figures from iftop match the figures from JDownloader. System monitor says I'm not downloading anything. Between the two I choose to trust iftop.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a way to set how often the display updates, which is a problem when running over ssh on a remote host, because it's using bandwidth just to send screen updates every second...

Answer (score 17):

You might want to look into `ntop` - which should monitor network activity on a process level. You can find `ntop` in the Software Center or with `sudo apt-get install ntop`

For installation instruction, follow their page http://packages.ntop.org/

Comment: not available with ubuntu 17.04 (zesty)

Comment: see http://packages.ntop.org/apt-stable/ for repos for later versions of ubuntu. also it's `apt-get install ntopng`

Comment: It has its own local server, and is sooo confusing...

Comment: E: Unable to locate package ntop  No, I will not install **and trust** a 3rd party package repository of a company I have never heard of.  If they haven't been bothered to keep up with the official ubuntu package system then it's probably not worth wasting energy on.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ ntopng appears to be part of the official 22.04 package system

Answer (score 13):

Here's one I like, it tells you what's reading from the network the most, anyway (doesn't seem to work for which one is "writing to" the network, so...you get half).

```
$ sudo apt install dstat
then
$ dstat --net --top-io-adv
-net/total- -------most-expensive-i/o-process-------
 recv  send|process              pid  read write cpu
   0     0 |chrome               1885   19k  17k0.4%
 504B  734B|chrome               1923    0   66k0.2%
 651k   18k|chrome               1923  597k 593k2.0%
  19k   26k|gnome-terminal-      25834 429B  59k0.8%
```

Comment: `dstat` is dead because it's name was taken over, see https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19986646

`dool` is the successor fork which is [not yet packaged in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1032875)

Comment: Yeah it's not well maintained, but I still use it.  The package in Ubuntu is still `dstat`, not sure on other distros :)

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative is `iptraf`. It won't show you the PID of the process, but will tell you which connection uses how much bandwidth.

Answer (score 8):

Late answer, but I had the same problem. Turned out to be Ubuntuone. Found that by running tcpdump. I went through the same learning curve on process identification.

From [my notes](http://tinkerstoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/08/ubuntu-box-connection-information.html):

> ### Ubuntu box connection information
>
> Started up my Ubuntu 10.04 desktop this morning to find that after a few minutes the Internet connection is crawling. I've seen this on Windows boxes before, and 99% of the time it's spyware. So, I needed to investigate...command line style.
>
> `tcpdump`. Shows Ubuntuone going crazy.
>
> System>Preferences>Ubuntu One. Turn all synchronization off. That did it.
>
> So, I'm thinking I'd like to see all network connections and what they're doing. I can
>
> `netstat -cW` (list network connections continuously in wide format so foreign addresses aren't truncated)
>
> `lsof -i |grep -v` 'localhost' (list open files matching an Internet address of any, grep to remove any open files associated with localhost -- my thought here being that I don't want to see local services as they likely will not affect network utilization).
>
> Some things to take away:
>
> 1. Need to learn about Ubuntu logs for troubleshooting.
> 2. Need to learn more about tcpdump, so I'll start with [this tutorial by Daniel Miessler](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/).

---

<sup>**Editor's note:** This answer was referring to [tinker's blogspot article](http://tinkerstoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/08/ubuntu-box-connection-information.html) which is meant for invited users only. Since this answer has appreciable upvotes, so it is valuable. I found a copy of article on [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20151004003828/http://tinkerstoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/08/ubuntu-box-connection-information.html). And included that here.</sup>