# How do I find out which program is using internet and how much?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, internet, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth)

Sometimes there is unusual internet activity on my Computer. The modem's lights are always blinking and when I open system monitor, I see there some unknown program is using my precious internet with 64KB/S (I have 512kbps connection). I am in a firefox session with only one tab opened, and the page is already loaded and there is no busy sign in the page (that rotating orange circle).

In that situation I unplug my modem and reconnect it again. After several times doing this, that unusual activity stops. It annoys me very much.

**How can I find out the process which is using the Internet?. How much it is using? How can I kill it?**

A graphical solution will be better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- NetHogs may help (`sudo apt-get install nethogs`)
- Run with `sudo nethogs <interface>` (interface can be eth0, wlan0, etc.), and observe it for a while:

[image]

- Then use `htop` (install if necessary) to "graphically" kill the process. You will probably get better results by telling us which process it is and then disabling it, instead of swatting it like a fly every time it pops up ;)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. And this solved my problem. There was a python application using the whole bandwidth. It seems that you have it too in the picture you've sent :) What is that?

Comment: And how can I see acumulated total of consumed bandwith  ?

Comment: I dont know the interface. I use `sudo nethogs -a`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [IPTraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) can help you.
I don't use it, but it seems to do what you need.

[image: this image]