# Why is evolution-calendar uploading and downloading high amount of data in background?

Tags: 16.04, networking, gnome, evolution

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Gnome. I use the system monitor widget and noted that network usage was unusually high both for downloading and uploading. I find this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152093/how-do-i-find-out-which-program-is-using-internet-and-how-much) and I installed `nethogs` to check what happened and found that network usage for the process `/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess` was pretty high.

[image: high_network_usage]

In the online accounts window I turned off and on the calendar item, and after that the process came reduced network usage.

[image: widget]

[image: normal_network_usage]

Could it be a known bug? Was it sending/downloading data without consentment?

---

**EDIT**:

Running Wireshark I identified a lot of TCP/TLS requests to apidata.googleusercontent.com:

[image: Wireshark_ss]

is this of any help?

Comment: Good question! Did you find an answer?

Comment: No, I just ran Wireshark and found a lot of TCP/TLS connection to apidata.googleusercontent.com. I will update the question with that information