# Internet bandwidth consumption monitor process wise monitoring?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, monitoring, bandwidth

I had some three or four askubuntu pages open in my firefox's tabs, and the pages suddenly started responding extremely slow. I checkd the system monitor, and it showed huge amounts of data being downloaded and it was continuous at the highest bandwidth my DSL connection can offer with some notches at intervals. I couldn't figure out the reason why it happened, couldn't draw any conclusions from the monitors process information. Then I closed the browser, and the download graph went down too.

I need help with some command tool/script (preferable) that would instantly display an ordered list of the processes consuming my bandwidth. (some packet tracing utility? bandwidth consumption monitor?) And please summarize how to get it done.

**Update 1:** I tried `nethogs` and made some test download with web broswer and other tools. `nethogs` did show what programs were consuming the bandwidth, (please note that previously in my problem I too guessed it was firefox, but the actual problem was ***what in firefox is devouring my bandwidth?*** It's not auto-update! I don't think I've configured anything for autoupdates in my system.) I want the suggested tools to show me what things are being downloaded and not just the client; *for example the tool should say* `"it's chromium-browser downloading file1.something and file2.somethingelse"`.

Comment: what is your connection?(broadband, wifi or Lan)

Comment: sorry moderators and reviewers but the [said "original"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth) post does not answer my question..

Comment: can't think of a real answer, but something like wireshark or the aircrack-ng utils might point you in the right direction, if you've got some scripting chops. i agree this is not a dupe