# Computer hogging bandwidth, how do I find out what it is?

Tags: bandwidth

My computer is hogging the house bandwidth and I have not idea why? Could it be a virus? How do I find out?

Comment: Start with the command "top" or if you want install "htop" and use that.  "virus"? VERY unlikely. Virus tend to be low key so they can keep hidden (not that we have any virusses yet :D )

Answer (score 0):

Virus is unlikely, if you're running Linux. You can see every process with a network connection open with:

```
sudo lsof -i
```

and, of course `man lsof`.

`top` will show you all the processes on your system, and `man top` will show the options and commands to use `top`.

Se also [this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth?rq=1)