# How can I measure the throughput of Samba?

Tags: samba

How can I measure the throughput of Samba?
I want to know how much bytes of data enters or leaves the samba server via Samba.
Do you know a command to get that numbers?

Comment: Related: [How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth)