# how do I find out which external IPs are consuming most part of my server's bandwidth

Tags: command-line, networking, server

My internal service recently being crashed by an unknow traffic coming from our local network

The symptom is, there is a significant traffic pushing to service, make the load spike up in sudden and the service is down.
The traffic comes in very fast, in just 1-2 minutes so I don't have enough time to remote into the server and tracing

So my question is:

- any command to indicate the top most external IPs which consumes the most bandwidth on the server
- so that I could do a loop to running it every 10-15 seconds or so

I'm running on Ubuntu 18

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can Google this. For example: https://linuxhint.com/top-10-ubuntu-network-tools/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth)