# Ubuntu hogging internet data even when idle

Tags: networking, 20.04, internet, malware, task-management

Ubuntu 20.04. I just connected my Ubuntu laptop that has negligible amount of apps installed to my WiFi. It's the only connected device to the router. My router is blinking rapidly, it does that when there is a good amount of data transfer. I'm doing nothing at all on my laptop and it's just turned on. Generally, my router blinks led that fast when I'm watching a 4k video online or doing some downloading. I want like this to stop because I don't know what data transfers are going in the background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth). This will help you track down traffic on your Ubuntu installation. However, make sure you don't jump to conclusions based on very little information. Your router blinking for data transfer could be *anything* and doesn't really have anything to do with the quantity of data being transmitted. You don't even know that it's coming from your Ubuntu device.

Comment: Change your wifi password.