# Cumulative network usage of applications

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

I'm wondering how to see a cumulative network usage broken down by individual applications, i.e. all usage until statistics are reset? I need it to identify why all my cellular data is being consumed.

I'm not interested in:

1. usage per interface, or...
2. simply "real time" usage monitoring that requires me to predict when and where an app is going to misbehave in order for me to run the tool — if I could do that I wouldn't need a tool.

Monitoring should be always active in the background and the stats need to be readily available after the fact.

The tools I've seen recommended so far don't seem to fit into this use case. For example `nethogs` is described as:

> shows current network usage by processes (program names)

Where "current usage" doesn't satisfy #2.

Comment: how does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: Network monitoring is typically a part of any (semi-)professional firewall solution. By inspecting traffic, and finding out which ports are used, you should be able to narrow down which services and applications are generating the traffic.

Comment: @24601 The applications run on Ubuntu.

Comment: If no one can motivate any of the downvotes then I can't do much else than to disregard them as noise...

Comment: such comment does not help your cause. Read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which process is eating up my bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth)

Comment: @24601 What is my cause? Just telling the truth. Perhaps less openness is advocated when resolving things?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find is `dstat`, which is taken from [this existing question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1230070/1066942):

```
$ sudo apt install dstat
```

then

```
$ dstat --net --top-io-adv
-net/total- -------most-expensive-i/o-process-------
 recv  send|process              pid  read write cpu
   0     0 |chrome               1885   19k  17k0.4%
 504B  734B|chrome               1923    0   66k0.2%
 651k   18k|chrome               1923  597k 593k2.0%
  19k   26k|gnome-terminal-      25834 429B  59k0.8%
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it